# Auto-linking paths containing spaces in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When you include a link to a filename with spaces in an e-mail message, Microsoft Office Outlook truncates the link at the first space. If the first space is in the network path or location of the file, the link is truncated at that point.

For instance,  if you type `\\UNCPath\My File WithSpace.doc` into the body of the message, Outlook converts only the first part of the text to a link, as in the following example:

```
\\UNCPath\My
```

This is not a valid link to the file.

How can we go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `<\\UNCPath\My File With Space.doc>` .

The "<" and ">" will be used as start and end tags for the UNC hyperlink.

Comment: this works for me

Comment: This has bugged me for years.  Too bad it's not more intuitive or automatic when you paste into Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Just put quotes around it when you enter it:

```
"\\UNCPath\My File With Spaces.doc"
```